# What counts as a paid app?

Tags: android, google-play, publish, publishing

As you may know Google doesn't allow developers in certain countries to publish paid applications to Google Play. However, they don't exactly clarify what counts as a paid application?!

Let me clear this up a little bit:

On [one of their support page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/150324) they have a list of countries what tells us where can developers publish paid applications but they don't mention anything about what counts as a paid application, and on one of their [other support page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138294?hl=en) (which clarifies that in which country can users download/buy applications) they do tell us that applications with in-app purchases fall under the paid category. Now I'm absolutely confused, and can't decide if this applies to developers too or not.

I mean, I can't decide if this means that developers who live in a country where they can publish only free apps can actually publish a free application with in-app purchases and only the users are restricted to this rule, or even developers who can only publish free apps can't put apps with in-app purchases to Google Play? If that's the case, is there any workaround for this? Also, applications with ads count as a paid app?

So, my real question would be that developers who can only publish free apps simply just can't get any money out of their work?

*P.M.: Sorry for my bad English.*

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Google-support](http://www.google.com/contact/) is better fit to answer your question.